# (cipher program) Index out of range error

Tags: python, arrays, encryption, indexing

I am making a program for a cipher following NDev's YT video, the error that comes up is index out of range and I am new to python here is my code:

```
charToBin = {
  "a":1,
  "b":10,
  "c":11,
  "d":100,
  "e":101,
  "f":110,
  "g":111,
  "h":1000
}
binToWrd = {
  1:"Intel",
  10:"Info",
  11:"Indipendent",
  101:"Imposibble",
  100:"Info-stolen",
  110:"Indian-Ogres",
  111:"Initially",
  1000:"Infant-Orphan-Ogre-Ogle"
}

endTxt = " "
cipher = " "

def txtToBin():
  global endTxt
  txt = input(":")
  txtArray = txt.split(" ")
  for x in range(len(txt)):
    endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
  print(endTxt)

def binToCip():
  global cipher
  codeTxtArr = endTxt.split(" ")
  for x1 in codeTxtArr:
    for x2 in binToWrd:
      cipher += x1.replace(str(x2), binToWrd[x2])
  print(cipher)

txtToBin()
binToCip()
```

The error that is returned when I enter b a d in the input:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    txtToBin()
  File "main.py", line 30, in txtToBin
    endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Let's say you entered "b a d".  That has a length of 5.  You split it into txtArray, which has a length of 3, but your `for` loop uses `len(txt)`, so it is still going to 5.  You don't need any of that split stuff.  I'll show you below.

Comment: Ok, I will check that

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've changed several things here.

First, globals are evil.  Your functions don't need them.  Your function should have an input and an output.  The input goes in as parameters, the output comes out as a return.

Second, in a utility function like this, don't do I/O.  Let the caller figure out how to get and present the data, and just have the function do the work.  That means don't do `print` in the function.  Instead, return the value and let the caller do the `print`.  That way, you can reuse this function in other places.  Simple, reusable functions are the key to productivity.

Third, any time you write `for x in range(len(y)):`, there is almost always a better way to write it, usually as `for x in y:`.  Python is perfectly happy to deliver each element to you one by one.  You don't have to do the indexing.

I'm not sure why you have your encodings as integer values here, since you need to convert them to strings for printing.  You might as well just have the encoded values be strings: `"1", "10", "11"`, etc.  You do understand those are not binary numbers, right?  That's one, ten, eleven, one hundred, etc?

Both of your functions could be turned into one-liners using a list comprehension.  I'll show that after.

```
charToBin = {
  "a":1,
  "b":10,
  "c":11,
  "d":100,
  "e":101,
  "f":110,
  "g":111,
  "h":1000
}
binToWrd = {
  1:"Intel",
  10:"Info",
  11:"Indipendent",
  101:"Imposibble",
  100:"Info-stolen",
  110:"Indian-Ogres",
  111:"Initially",
  1000:"Infant-Orphan-Ogre-Ogle"
}

def txtToBin(txt):
    endTxt = []
    for c in txt.split():
        endTxt.append( str(charToBin[c]) )
    return ' '.join(endTxt)

def binToCip(code):
    cipher = []
    for x1 in code.split():
        cipher.append( binToWrd[int(x1)])
    return ' '.join(cipher)

endTxt = txtToBin(input(":"))
print(endTxt)
cipher = binToCip(endTxt)
print(cipher)
```

Alternatively:

```
def txtToBin(txt):
    return ' '.join( str(charToBin[c]) for c in txt.split() )

def binToClip(code):
    return ' '.join( binToWord[int(c)] for c in code.split() )
```